# How do I place a label over an AVPlayer playing a video?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I place a label over or "on top of" an AVPlayer playing a video? I have tried adjusting Z-position as suggested in another SO post but it is not working, the video player seems to be in the front of all the labels.

```
    //this is my label

    self.commentLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.commentLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
    [self.commentLabel sizeToFit];
    self.commentLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/1.4);
    self.commentLabel.layer.zPosition=100;

    //this is my video player

    self.playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    NSString*str3=[self.FRIENDDATA stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://my.website.com/%@/%@.mp4", str3,self.RANDOMDATA]];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL: url];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: asset];
    AVPlayer * player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem: item];
    self.playerViewController.player = player;
    [self.playerViewController.view setFrame:self.referenceImageView.frame];
    self.playerViewController.view.layer.zPosition=0;
    self.playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.playerViewController.view];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the label subview onto the playerViewController ?

```
[self.playerViewController.view addSubview:self.commentLabel];
```

From the code I am unsure if commentLabel is not yet initialized or if it initialized somewhere else in the code or from a storyboard. It would be great to initialize the `commentLabel` on the `playerViewController`

Like this:

```
UILabel *commentLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/1.4, 100, 100)];

[self.playerViewController.view addSubview:commentLabel];
```

That should resolve your issue

Comment: Adding a sub view to a view controller?  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: This worked! I actually added: [self.playerViewController.view addSubview:self.commentLabel] since I initialized the label in the storyboard and it is now visible over the playerViewController. Thank you!